# Spring AOP BeanCreationException due to "formal unbound in pointcut"

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, aspect

I have problem with Spring AOP.

I'm trying to implement aspects in Spring MVC aplication.

The error I get is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0':
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
```

What causes this problem?

In XML file I have this:

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

My aspect class:

```java
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ApplicationMonitor {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationMonitor.class);

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* hr.mycompany.controller.impl.MyCompanyController.update(Object))") 
    public void updateMC(Object obj){}

    @Before(value="ApplicationMonitor.updateMC(Object)")
    public void beforeUpdateMC(JoinPoint jp) {
        Object obj = jp.getArgs()[0];
        logger.info("beforeUpdateMC " + obj);
    }
}
```

In pom.xml file I have this dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT (after change pointcut):**

I changed pointcut and now I'm getting errors like this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hr.mycompany.dao.IGenericHibernateDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}


09:11:27,871 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/BasicData-portlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8083-2) StandardWrapper.Throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyCompanyService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private hr.mycompany.dao.IGenericHibernateDao hr.mycompany.services.impl.MyCompanyService.vwObjectDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hr.mycompany.dao.IGenericHibernateDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My app has multiple layers and classes like this:

```
@Controller 
public class MyCompanyController implements IMyCompanyController{

    @Autowired
    private IMyComapnyService myCompanyService;

}


@Service
public class MyCompanyService implements IMyComapnyService {

    @Autowired
    private IGenericHibernateDao<Object, Integer>  vwObjectDao;

}
```

I'm trying to make advice for @Controller and @Service @Autowired method.

Comment: You have to add `and args(obj)` in `@Pointcut(value = "execution(* hr.mycompany.controller.impl.MyCompanyController.update(Object))")` like `@Pointcut(value = "execution(* hr.mycompany.controller.impl.MyCompanyController.update(Object)) and args(obj)")`

Comment: It is not `and`, it is `&&`. Maybe everyone answering here should first learn Spring AOP or AspectJ syntax. ;-)

Comment: @kriegaex: I actually read in book spring in action 4th edition by manning and as per book, it supports both but just tested and it seems you are right.

Comment: `AND` is AFAIK only used in XML configuration where ampersands and pipes are rather nasty.

Comment: Yes you are right, it's used in XML

Answer (score 1):

User *heonlyrao* suggested the right thing but with the wrong pointcut syntax. You want to do this:

```java
    @Pointcut("execution(* hr.mycompany.controller.impl.MyCompanyController.update(*)) && args(obj)") 
    public void updateMC(Object obj) {}

    @Before("updateMC(obj)")
    public void beforeUpdateMC(JoinPoint jp, Object obj) {
        // Not needed if parameter is bound via args()
        // Object obj = jp.getArgs()[0];
        logger.info("beforeUpdateMC " + obj);
    }
```

Or, similar to *heonlyrao*'s suggestion and if you do not re-use the same pointcut in multiple advices, you can also inline it:

```java
    @Before("execution(* hr.mycompany.controller.impl.MyCompanyController.update(*)) && args(obj)")
    public void beforeUpdateMC(JoinPoint jp, Object obj) {
        // Not needed if parameter is bound via args()
        // Object obj = jp.getArgs()[0];
        logger.info("beforeUpdateMC " + obj);
    }
```

Explanation: Your error message says: `formal unbound in pointcut`. This means that you are either using a formal parameter in your pointcut and/or advice method signature which is not reflected in the pointcut or vice versa.

Comment: I changed pointcut and now I'm getting errors like this:


    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hr.mycompany.dao.IGenericHibernateDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    
    
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyCompanyService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Comment: I have mulitilayer app and I'm trying to advice @ Controller and @ Service class methods

Comment: That is a follow up configuration problem and unrelated to the original question.

Comment: Could you please tell me where the problem is?

Comment: I cannot because it seems to be a configuration (e.g. bean naming) problem and I cannot see your configuration because there is no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As the problem is no longer AOP-related and I am an AOP expert, not a Spring user, and as the new problem is about dependency injection, I think you should close this question by accepting my answer, create an MCVE for your new problem and then ask a new question with the MCVE and maybe a link back to this question so people can understand where you were coming from. Thanks, Chris. :-)

Comment: I will create MCVE. Thank you for your answers!